Nginx Location Exact Match (location = /) Causing 404 Error Despite File Existing
I have an Nginx server configuration where I'm trying to serve a specific file home.html when a user accesses the root URL /. Here’s my Nginx configuration:
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
 location = / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/app2;
    index home.html;
 }
}

and the folder structure for /usr/share/nginx/html is
html
|-- 50x.html
|-- app1
| -- index.html
|-- app2
| |-- home.html
-- index.html

and home.html file is
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello from app2</h1>
</body>
</html>

The Issue:
When I try to access http://localhost/ using curl or a web browser, I get a 404 Not Found error instead of the home.html file being served. The access log shows the following entry:
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-"
It seems like Nginx is catching the location = / directive but is not serving the home.html file as expected. I suspect it might be doing an internal redirect, but I'm unsure why this is happening since the file exists and is correctly referenced in the configuration.
What I’ve Tried:

Confirmed that the home.html file is indeed located at /usr/share/nginx/html/app2/home.html.
Checked file permissions to ensure that Nginx can read the file.
Verified that there are no other conflicting location blocks or server blocks in my Nginx configuration.
Restarted the Nginx service after making any changes.

Despite these checks, I still encounter the 404 error. I’m not sure if I’m missing something specific about how Nginx handles exact location matches.

The index directive changes the URL to /home.html then looks again for a matching location. Which no longer matches location = /.

Enabling the debug log ( error_log /path/to/log debug; ) will allow you to see what nginx is doing, and allow you to serve solve this and future questions :)

@RichardSmith , Ok index directive will change the url to /home.html. as = /  is already executed, this location will not matched further because of =. What i want to know now is that if i remove =. what will happen is first time location will match with / then index directive will do the internal redirection to usr/share/nginx/html/app2/index.html and nginx will try to find location with updated uri. then again it will match / location. then will it again redirect with index directive ? Doesn't it make loop ? if not why ?

@JaswinderSingh_6080_M, the index directive only operates on URLs that end with a /. Also, they must point to a directory which contains a filename matching one specified in the statement.

@RichardSmith, Could you please elaborate

@JaswinderSingh_6080_M, in the location = / block, replace the line index home.html; with try_files /home.html =404;

You should remove = from location.
Final Nginx configuration should be like this:
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
 location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/app2;
    index home.html;
 }
}

